# What the hell is that noise and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I've now for the second time encountered a multiplayer match where there was a constant background noise. The first time I thought someone was just messing around and played some sound effect via his microphone, but I now encountered exactly the same sound effect a second time.

The effect is pretty much audible the whole match, it's not a constant hum but an oscillating one, and it's very annoying.

What causes this annoying sound and how do I make sure I don't encounter it a third time?

Comment: Is this the Husk language? If that's the case, it should stop between waves, and start up again when a new wave spawns.

Comment: Yeah, I got that earlier today too.

Comment: Sounds like feedback from your own mic or someone elses

Comment: @Resorath it's definitely an in-game sound effect, not a mic

Comment: @benbrocka feedback doesn't emit from a mic but can be caused by the presence of one - damaged or improperly calibrated

Comment: More detail would be helpful- what map, etc.

Comment: The sound was constant, not only during waves. And I'm sure that it wasn't my mic as I never activated it (it's push to talk in ME3). It happened on two different maps, I don't remember their names though.

Comment: Does it sound like this (Warning: Turn DOWN your volume first): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TwmGciViz8#t=330s

Comment: @Resorath No, it sounds like some real ingame sound effect looping for too long

Comment: another annoying sound is the stupid charging noise of the geth plasma shotgun, I hate those things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I know what you're talking about. I experienced this myself as well. It's the sound of **Reave**'s sound effect looping over and over. I think this is a bug, as I have not yet figured out a consistent way to stop it. You can see this person cast Reave [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=xvCPCJB37LI#t=8s) in singleplayer, and the sound effect lasts for a good 20 seconds.

I've had it continue to loop for me even after the wave was finished and all the enemies were dead.  There doesn't seem to be anything you can do about it. :/ It's even more annoying than running effect soundlooping in the lobby menu that I've had occur.

The only way I can guarantee avoiding it is not teaming with any Drell Adepts.

Comment: That's exactly the sound I was hearing, let's hope Bioware fixes that soon. It's bloody annoying.

Comment: FWIW, I've been playing a Drell adept all weekend, and had no issues with the Reave sound effect. It lasts as long as the buff from Reave is active on the player who cast it, and no longer, and I found it a useful audio cue for when my DR buff was going to fade.

Comment: Still happening, and now asari adept/justicars have Reave too! Hooray (and by "hooray" I mean "man that woobly noise can bite me").

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has to do with a drell adept. I was playing for the past couple games with one, and it was going the entire time. After a while, it starts to give me a headache and makes me nauseous. I definitely need to quit after a bit of that sound playing. I really hope Bioware fixes this sound because after a while, I just have to turn the in-game sound off so that I can play in peace.

Answer (score 0):

The sound effect is indeed caused by a bug with the Drell Adept's Reave ability as the other users have mentioned. As far as getting rid of it, [this post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/MECoOp/comments/r624w/drell_adepts_use_pull_twice_quickly_at_the_end_of/) suggests using the Pull ability twice in quick succession at the end of a round should do the trick.

I don't have a Drell Adept to test this with, but I would recommend suggesting that your Drell teammates give it a try.

Answer (score -2):

The Drell have a skill that makes some weird sounds, maybe that's what you're hearing.